# Setting Mercurial options with JavaHg

Tags: java, mercurial, javahg

How are `--config` options interpreted by JavaHg and the Mercurial command server if I set them with the [`cmdAppend` method](http://javahg.aragost.com/apidocs/com/aragost/javahg/internals/AbstractCommand.html)? The method has no Javadoc yet.

Will they persist from call to call or will they reset automatically after each call to an `execute` method?

Comment: (This question was asked to me in private — I'm re-posting it here with an answer in case others have the same question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaHg does not do anything special with arguments added with `cmdAppend` — they go directly to the command server. An option set with

```java
cmd.cmdAppend("--config", "a.b=x");
```

will only be effective for the next `cmd.execute();`. This is [tested right here in JavaHg](https://bitbucket.org/aragost/javahg/src/0fc239862a01/src/test/java/com/aragost/javahg/internals/ServerTest.java#cl-123).

The Mercurial command server resets the configuration between requests so this will also apply for other command server clients.